In a club with 100 people, if each person (except A) has a distinct number of acquaintances (including A), how many people does A know?
I was given the following exercise in my Combinatorics class:
"A club X has 100 members. Person A then joins the club. 2 people in the club either knows each other or don't. A notices that, except for A, each of the remaining 100 members has a distinct number of acquaintances, including A. How many people does A know in the club?"
I think I have a solution but I'm open to other solutions or corrections to my solution if it's wrong (which I think it is...?).
Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $∣V∣=101$, where $V$ represents the set of vertices (people) in the graph, and $E$ represents the edges (relationships between people). Since there can't be both a vertex with degree $0$ and a vertex with degree $100$, the degrees of vertices in G must be $0,1,2,...,99$ or $1,2,3,...,100$. We'll look into each cases separately:

For case $0,1,2,...,99$

Vertex with degree $99$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertex with degree $0$

Vertex with degree $98$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degrees $0$ and $1$

Vertex with degree $97$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degrees $0, 1$, and $2$

...

Vertex with degree $50$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degrees $0, 1, 2,  ...,$ and $49$


Since there are 50 vertices from degree 50 to 99, A is adjacent to 50 vertices. So A knows 50 people

For case $1,2,3,...,100$

Vertex with degree $100$ is adjacent to every other vertices

Vertex with degree $99$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degree $1$

Vertex with degree $98$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degreew $0$ and $1$

...

Vertex with degree $51$ is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degreew $0, 1, 2,  ...,$ and $49$


Since there are 50 vertices from degree 51 to 100, A is adjacent to 50 vertices. So A knows 50 people.



in general, in a party of $n>3$ people excluding $A$, I believe $A$ will know $\frac{n}{2}$ people if $n$ is even and $\frac{n-1}{2}$ people if $n$ is odd. I will try to prove this in a different manner.
(for $n \le 3$ I believe it depends on whether you allow for a person who doesn't know anyone.)

I mean $\frac{n+1}{2}$, my bad

@EdmaandVladPhiyik  the situation is tricky for odd membered clubs (pre $A$).  Say the club only had $1$ member before $A$ joins.  Then the assumption is vacuously satisfied, but we can't determine the result.  Maybe $A$ knows the other member, maybe not.  For even numbers, I agree with your conjecture.

@lulu right, got it. there is also ambiguity for $n=3$. I guess, it depends on whether we allow a person with degree $0$. can we say $A$ knows $\frac{n+1}{2}$ persons if there is no such person in the party who doesn't know anyone, and A knows $\frac{n-1}{2}$ people if there a person in the party who doesn't know anyone.

@EdmaandVladPhiyik  I expect that there is a modified version that works.  As I pointed out in my posted solution below (for the even case), there is a duality between the given problem and the one in which "knows" is replaced by "doesn't know".  In the even case the two problems have the same result, but in the odd case, they don't.

I didn't review your argument, but here is a different approach:
Induction on $k$, where the $A-$less club contains $2k$ people.  We want to show that the assumption implies that $A$ knows exactly $k$ people.
Base case:  $k=1$.  Say the $A-$less club contained two members, $p_1, p_2$.  Either they know each other or they don't.  Either way, $A$ must know exactly one of them to break the symmetry.
Now suppose that we know the desired result for $k$ and look at a club with $2(k+1)$ non $A$ members.  Call them $\{p_1, \cdots, p_{2k+2}\}$.  Letting $a_i$ denote the number of members $p_i$ knows (possibly including $A$) we sort them in increasing order.  Clearly it is impossible to realize both of $a_1=0$ and $a_{2k+2}=2k+2$ but we must realize one of those and by symmetry we may assume that $a_1=0$ (Symmetry:  switching from "know" to "not know" just makes an equivalent, "dual" problem).
Given that $a_1=0$ we may delete $p_1$  and consider the club with $2k+1$ members, pre $A$.  Now, of course, $p_{2k+2}$ knows everybody including $A$, so we may delete them as well and consider the club with $2k$ members.  The point, to stress, is that if somebody knows everybody (or if they know nobody), you can delete them from the club and then the number of people a surviving member knows drops by $1$ (or stays the same) and the assumed property still holds.  But now we are down to the same problem for a club with $2k$ members so we can invoke the induction hypothesis. Thus $A$ knows exactly $k$ members of the diminished club and of course $A$ knows $p_{2k+2}$ by assumption, so $A$ knows exactly $k+1$ members of the original, and we are done.

Small note: the base case can be taken as $k=0$ (which is completely trivial to check), since the inductive step never requires $k>0$, and so works perfectly well with $k = 0$ to going from the of a $(0+1)$-member club to a $(2+1)$-member club.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine  Absolutely correct.

Another (equivalent) way to see @lulu's answer is to construct the club sequentially.
Start with $V_1 = \{a_1, b_1\} \cup \{A\}$ and edge $a_1A \in E_1$. Note that

if $a_1 b_1 \not\in E_1$, then $|N(b_1)| = 0$ and $|N(a_1)| = 1$,
whereas if $a_1 b_1 \in E_1$, then $|N(b_1)| = 1$ and $|N(a_1)| = 2$, and
Either way, the neighborhood $N_{G_1}(A)$ of $A$ is $\{a_1\}$.

Now define $V_2 = V_1 \cup \{a_2, b_2\}$ and build
$E_2$ from $E_1$ by adding $\{a_2 v \;|\; v \in V_1\}$ and, if $a_1 b_1 \in E_1$, the edge $a_2 b_2$. Note now that

Everybody in $V_1$ has seen their degree incremented by 1, so all of their degrees in $E_2$ are still distinct; the degree of $b_2$ is one less than that of $b_1$, and the degree of $a_2$ is one more than that of $a_1$.

$N_{G_2}(A) = \{a_1, a_2\}$.


It's straightforward to see that one can iterate this process, defining each successive $V_i$ as $V_{i-1} \cup \{a_i, b_i\}$, and making $a_i$ adjacent to everybody in $V_{i-1}$ and also, if $a_1 b_1 \in E_1$, to $b_i$. And the invariants still hold:

the degrees in $G_i$ of everybody in $V_i \setminus \{A\}$ are all unique, and

$N_{G_i}(A) = \{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_i\}$, so the degree of $A$ is $i = \frac{|V_i| - 1}{2}$.



Your solution is right, but it could be made more clear with a bit of additional explanation:
Instead of directly saying

Vertex with degree 99 is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertex with degree 0
Vertex with degree 98 is adjacent to every other vertices except for the vertices with degrees 0 and 1
...

you could explain this by saying

Vertex with degree 0 knows noone, so the vertex with degree 99 must know every other vertex.
Vertex with degree 1 already knows 99, so 0, 1 don't know 98, which must therefore know everyone else.
2 knows 98,99, so 0,1,2 don't know 97, so it knows everyone else.
...

The other case is symmetric.
